# Why I get an Exception 18 when I try to get the image data of an Image with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in the response header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, cors

When I try to get the pixels of an image through the method getImageData, I've got this error

> "Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been
>   tainted by cross-origin data. Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM
>   Exception 18"

The image has **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *** in the header response. So, I don't understand why I got this error. What I have to do to solve this problem?.

I've tried to add the attribute crossOrigin to the image, but this does not work in Safari.
The code I am working on is below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        var ctx = $('#cnv')[0].getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        var originalImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 300); // Exception 18
    };
    img.src = 'http://api.thumbr.it/1f86404a001828912f295a74b8a4d337/D-lvXHFIHpY/api.thumbr.it/static/ladies-800.png/400x400c-ebrown-eframe1/thumb.jpg';
    $('body').append(img);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Example</h1>
<img class="image" id="img-rara" src="http://api.thumbr.it/f4414f15f6d6d2639a17c6e1c025d970/D-lvXHFIHpY/api.thumbr.it/static/ladies-800.png/400x400c-ebarcelona-eframe1/thumb.jpg" />
<canvas id="cnv" width="711" height="400" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client-side, be sure to set the `crossOrigin` flag before setting the img.src

```
img.crossOrigin='anonymous'
```

Here's your code with crossorigin access set to anonymous:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        var ctx = $('#cnv')[0].getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        var originalImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 300); // Exception 18
    };

    // allow cross-origin access
    img.crossOrigin='anonymous' 

    img.src = 'http://api.thumbr.it/1f86404a001828912f295a74b8a4d337/D-lvXHFIHpY/api.thumbr.it/static/ladies-800.png/400x400c-ebrown-eframe1/thumb.jpg';
    $('body').append(img);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Example</h1>
<img class="image" id="img-rara" src="http://api.thumbr.it/f4414f15f6d6d2639a17c6e1c025d970/D-lvXHFIHpY/api.thumbr.it/static/ladies-800.png/400x400c-ebarcelona-eframe1/thumb.jpg" />
<canvas id="cnv" width="711" height="400" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The crossOrigin attribute works in browsers such as Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't work in Safari. So ... do you know another way to get the image data? Thank you!

Comment: Ok, it's kind of hackish.....but you can wrap the image url up in a jsonP request and bounce it off a server.  Since it's coming back as json, the cross-origin police ignore it.  If you don't have time to configure it out, here's a lib that does it for you: http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to solve this problem through XMLHttpRequest. This solution is valid for Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera but **not in IE**. Visit this page **http://jsperf.com/encoding-xhr-image-data/12** for more information.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // See: http://jsperf.com/encoding-xhr-image-data/12
    $('body').ready(function(){
        data = getImageData(
            'http://api.thumbr.it/1f86404a001828912f295a74b8a4d337/D-lvXHFIHpY/api.thumbr.it/static/ladies-800.png/400x400c-ebrown-eframe1/thumb.jpg');
    });
    function getImageData(url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, false);
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
        xhr.send();

        var img = $('<img>');
        img.attr(
            'src',
            'data:image/' + getType(xhr.responseText.slice(0, 4)) + ';base64,' + getDataBase64(xhr.responseText)
        );
        img.load(function() {
            var ctx = $('#cnv')[0].getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(img[0], 0, 0);
            data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); // Data!!
        });
    }
    function getDataBase64(data) {
        var binary = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=4) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode(
                data.charCodeAt(i+0) & 0xff,
                data.charCodeAt(i+1) & 0xff,
                data.charCodeAt(i+2) & 0xff,
                data.charCodeAt(i+3) & 0xff
            );
        }
        for (i-=4; i < data.length; i+=1) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode(data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
        }
        return window.btoa(binary);
    }
    function getType(data) {
        if (data.search('PNG') >= 0) {
            return 'png';
        } else if (data.search('GIF') >= 0) {
            return 'gif';
        } else {
            return 'jpeg';
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Example</h1>
<img class="image" id="img-rara" src="http://api.thumbr.it/f4414f15f6d6d2639a17c6e1c025d970/D-lvXHFIHpY/api.thumbr.it/static/ladies-800.png/400x400c-ebarcelona-eframe1/thumb.jpg" />
<canvas id="cnv" width="400" height="400" />
</body>
</html>
```