# Canvas tainted eventhough image has Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, cdn

I am using CDN to server images to the site here: http://north.fuelthemes.net/

The CDN has "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" set for all images.

However the canvas is still tainted.

The images are used as background images.

Comment: Have you set to `.crossDomain` property of the images?

Comment: I cannot add the crossdomain="*" property to image tags since they 're background images, but while I am processing them, I use `img.crossDomain('anonymous');`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I get an Exception 18 when I try to get the image data of an Image with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: \* in the response header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238059/why-i-get-an-exception-18-when-i-try-to-get-the-image-data-of-an-image-with-acce)